# Run another javascript when user clicks "ok" on alertbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, alert

Basically I have a script that checks database every 10 seconds and notifys user if data has changed with a javascript alert box. But I need the database also to be changed when user has seen the alert and clicked OK. So is it possible to make a javascript function run when user clicks "OK" on javascript alert?

So for example

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_alert()
{
alert("New data!");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="show_alert()" value="Show alert box" />

</body>
</html>
```

And when user clicks OK it should run this function

```
  function UpdateDB()
  {
      jQuery.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "update.php",
       data: 'condition=ok',
       cache: false,

     });
 }
```

Comment: use confirm instead of alert http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptconfirm.php

Comment: @Bondye Nothing wrong with alert. He doesn't want user confirmation.

Comment: @Jivings What about `when user has seen the alert and clicked OK`

Comment: @Jiviings Precisely! This was why I posted my actually useful answer! which promptly got down voted... ha ha

Comment: In my case it is important for the user to only have the option to click OK, so I can't use confirm box

Comment: @user1323294, then you should rephrase  your question so that you're not asking for the OK to actually be a control of some kind... look at what you asked! "But I need the database also to be changed when user has seen the alert and clicked OK". The user's actions here are irrelevant. Once the alert is up, the only way to prevent further execution is to close the browser window without clicking "OK". That's not the correct way to approach this, obviously.  Your Alert is 100% useless (not to mention annoying to the user). There are better ways to notify someone than pop alerts in their face.

Comment: yes, usually this would probably not be the best way to notify the user. BUT in my case it is exactly what I need to do. The database has to be updated when the user sees the new data and there can't be an option to cancel the notification. That is why i precisely asked how to do this with alert box.

Comment: @user1323294, ok, well... I'm glad you found the answer you were looking for. I'll continue to suggest that you should put the alert as something that happens after the DB has actually been updated, so that if nothing else it serves the purpose of confirming that the transaction was successful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `alert` function halts execution of the code until it's dismissed. This means that any code you want to run after the alert has been clickd can simply be placed after the call to the `alert` method.

```
alert("New data!");
UpdateDB();
```

Comment: This works fine if I do just a function where it sends the data to server. But I need my function to also refresh the page after the POST. But when I add a success `success: function(response) 
{
window.location.reload()
}` it just keeps reloading again and again even without alert showing.

Comment: Can you put together a jsfiddle.net of how you're implimenting this and I'll take a look.

Comment: This is what I have been using : http://jsfiddle.net/FFMrz/ So it gets data from server every 10 seconds and if the data has changed it shows alert. And after the user has pressed OK button it should do the jQuery POST and then reload the window. But now it seems to POST and update the window automatically without the alert showing...

Comment: This part here `if(oldData != "") alert("New data!");`. Because you havent put curly braces around the content of the `if` statement, only the first line after the `if` is considered part of the `if`. The rest is outside of that an executes regardless of your condition check.

Answer (score 11):

What you're really looking for is the `confirm()`.  I don't think you can act on an alert's ok press (and really you don't want to since it doesn't leave the user the option to change their mind!)...

So...

```
if (confirm("Do you REALLY want this?")){
   //your AJAX CALL HERE
}
```

Comment: Not if he doesn't want user confirmation.

Comment: Forgetting for a moment that the OP actually asked PRECISELY for this  when he said... "when user has seen the alert and clicked OK",  What's the point of the Alert then? The user has pressed a button. If anything, you'll want the alert after the Ajax call comes back, otherwise it serves no purpose at all! And thanks for the down-vote. You're really helping the community with your diligence.  I'll be sure to think twice before bothering to try and help someone.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel You're making an assumption that it was me who downvoted you. Nevertheless, format your answer correctly and I'll remove it.

Comment: +1 Clearly this isn't an unreasonable answer considering it's how confirm boxes were designed to work. When asking questions where the use of some standard feature is unorthodox or out of the ordinary, the person asking the question should consider being really clear about explaining *why* he/she is using said feature in a manner that is contrary to conventional wisdom. Otherwise, potentially good answers get downvoted for simple, avoidable misunderstandings.

Comment: @Jivings, I made no such assumption. I was addressing whoever had downvoted me. I have formatted my code to be prettier. Feel free to upvote with impunity! :)

Comment: Thank you, even though this didn't answer OP's exact question, it answered the one I was looking for and this question was the top result

Answer (score 8):

```
function show_alert()
{
    alert("New data!");
    UpdateDB();
}
```