# How to change the text of the button to say "No Sign Ups!" after alert box is closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

New to jQuery and I need to change the text of the "Sign Up Now" button after the after the alert box is closed. From a pseudo-code standpoint, it seems like I should be creating a function that runs once the alert box is closed. I have tried numerous things both from my own guesses and from googling the matter and nothing seems to be working. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Relaxr Blog Page</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Relaxr Landing Page"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="relaxing, blog, tech startup, email, reply, meetings"/>
    <meta name="author" content="Chantel Zapata"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,300,600,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>

<!-- HEADER -->
<header class="header ">
    <div class="headercontainer">
    <h1 class="fl">Relaxr</h1>
    <nav class="main-nav fr">
        <ul>
            <li class="nav-element">About</li>
            <li class="nav-element">FAQ</li>
            <li class="nav-element">Team</li>
            <li class="nav-element">Contact Us</li>
            <li class="nav-element">Blog</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
</header>


<div class="content">
<!-- BLOG AREA -->
<div class="blog-area fl clearfix:after">
    <div class="">
        <h2>How I implemented Relaxr in 2 weeks and changed my life.<h2>
        <img src="images/blog_photo1.jpg" alt="Rowers" height="280" width="700"/>
        <p class="introduction">L</p><p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque at lobortis lectus. Proin faucibus nibh vitae purus elementum convallis. Quisque sagittis viverra facilisis. Nullam lobortis blandit lorem, at convallis arcu eleifend at. Nullam rhoncus, lacus at laoreet venenatis, ante orci ultrices felis, sed tempor nisi lorem at tortor. Proin vitae risus et felis interdum maximus. Mauris ac sollicitudin tortor, sit amet egestas nibh.</p>

        <p class="additionaltext1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque at lobortis lectus. Proin faucibus nibh vitae purus elementum convallis. Quisque sagittis viverra facilisis. Nullam lobortis blandit lorem, at convallis arcu eleifend at. Nullam rhoncus, lacus at laoreet venenatis, ante orci ultrices felis, sed tempor nisi lorem at tortor. Proin vitae risus et felis interdum maximus. Mauris ac sollicitudin tortor, sit amet egestas nibh.</p>

        <a class="blog-link read-more1 fr">Read more ></a>
        <a class="blog-link read-less1 fr">Read less ></a>
        <!-- I just selected a random blog link for now-->
    </div>
    <div class="divider">
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>I traveled across the globe thanks to Relaxr’s Excel auomation<h2>
        <img src="images/blog_photo2.jpg" alt="Boats" height="280" width="700"/>
        <p class="introduction">L</p><p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque at lobortis lectus. Proin faucibus nibh vitae purus elementum convallis. Quisque sagittis viverra facilisis. Nullam lobortis blandit lorem, at convallis arcu eleifend at. Nullam rhoncus, lacus at laoreet venenatis, ante orci ultrices felis, sed tempor nisi lorem at tortor. Proin vitae risus et felis interdum maximus. Mauris ac sollicitudin tortor, sit amet egestas nibh.</p>

        <p class="additionaltext2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque at lobortis lectus. Proin faucibus nibh vitae purus elementum convallis. Quisque sagittis viverra facilisis. Nullam lobortis blandit lorem, at convallis arcu eleifend at. Nullam rhoncus, lacus at laoreet venenatis, ante orci ultrices felis, sed tempor nisi lorem at tortor. Proin vitae risus et felis interdum maximus. Mauris ac sollicitudin tortor, sit amet egestas nibh.</p>

        <a class="blog-link read-more2 fr">Read more ></a>
        <a class="blog-link read-less2 fr">Read less ></a>
        <!-- I just selected a random blog link for now-->
    </div>
    <div class="divider">
    </div>
</div>

<!-- SIDE BAR -->
<aside class="side-bar fr clearfix:after">

    <div>
    <h3>Categories</h3>
    <ul class="side-bar-list">
        <li class="side-bar-nav">Success stories</li>
        <li class="side-bar-nav">Stats</li>
        <li class="side-bar-nav">How tos</li>
        <li class="side-bar-nav">Best of</li>
        <li class="side-bar-nav">Business tips</li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div>
    <h3>About Relaxr</h3>
    <p class="about-descrip">Proin vitae risus et felis interdum maximus. Mauris ac sollicitudin tortor, sit amet egestas nibh.<span class="learn-more-text">Mauris ac sollicitudin tortor, sit amet egestas nibh!</span></p>
    <a class="learn-more">Learn more</a>
    <!-- I just selected a random blog link for now-->
    </div>

    <img class="ad-unit" src="images/ad-unit.png" alt="Ad Unit" height="546" width="240"/>

</aside>
</div>


<!-- SIGN UP -->
<div class="bar clear">
    <a href="#" class="signupnow">Sign Up Now!</a>
    <!-- I just selected a random link that was "relaxing" for now-->
</div>

<!-- FOOTER -->
<footer>
    <h4>Relaxr</h4>
    <br />
    <a href="https://twitter.com/" class="social"> <img src="images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter Icon"></a>
    <a href="https://facebook.com/" class="social"> <img src="images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook Icon"></a>
    <br />
    <p>Copyright 2015. Relaxr.</p>
</footer>

 <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
* {
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firexfox */
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome/iOS/Android */
     box-sizing: border-box; /* IE */
}

/* Clear fix hack */
.clearfix:after {
     content: ".";
     display: block;
     clear: both;
     visibility: hidden;
     line-height: 0;
     height: 0;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.fr {
  float: right;
}

.fl {
  float: left;
}

/******************************************
/* ADDITIONAL STYLES
/*******************************************/


body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #f0efef;
}
h1 {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
}
h4 {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #f9e42e;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.bar {
  background-color: #f9e42e;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.signupnow {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 11px 56px 11px 56px;
  background: #033048;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #121212;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
footer p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
footer a {
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
.content {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

/* Header */
header {
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #033048;
}
header nav ul { 
  list-style: none; 
}
.nav-element {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #f9e42e;
}
.headercontainer {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Blogs */
.blog-area {
  width: 700px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 600px;
  color: #033048;
}
p {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-weight: 300px;
  color: #606161;
} 
.blog-link {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #033048;
}
.divider {
  height: 1px;
  width: 700px;
  background-color: #606161;
  margin-top: 160px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
p.introduction:first-letter {
 font-size: 380%;
 float: left;
 width: 1em;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-top: 28px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 padding-left: 0;
 font-weight: 600;
}
.additionaltext1 {
  display: none;
}
.additionaltext2 {
  display: none;
}
.read-less1 {
  display: none;
}
.read-less2 {
  display: none;
}

/* Side Bar */
.side-bar {
  width: 240px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #033048;
}
.side-bar-list {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #033048;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
    padding-left:0;
}
.learn-more {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #033048;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.about-descrip {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #033048; 
  text-align: left;
}
.side-bar-list {
  display: table;
}
.ad-unit {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.learn-more-text {
  display: none;
}
```

And my jQuery:

```
$('.signupnow')
    .on('click', function (){
    alert("We are not currently taking sign ups");
    });
$('.read-more1').on('click',function (){
    $('.additionaltext1').slideDown();
    });
$('.read-more2').on('click',function (){
    $('.additionaltext2').slideDown();
    });
$('.learn-more').on('click',function (){
    $('.learn-more-text').slideDown();
    });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715244/run-another-javascript-when-user-clicks-ok-on-alertbox

Comment: just after you call the alert, just change the text of the button, $(button).text('no signs up');

Answer (score 1):

As @ThisOneGuy said:

```
$('.signupnow')
    .on('click', function (){
    alert("We are not currently taking sign ups");
    $(button).text('no signs up');
    });
$('.read-more1').on('click',function (){
    $('.additionaltext1').slideDown();
    });
$('.read-more2').on('click',function (){
    $('.additionaltext2').slideDown();
    });
$('.learn-more').on('click',function (){
    $('.learn-more-text').slideDown();
    });
```